# Secure usage of SHA512

Tags: security, cryptography, sha, sha512

I have a question about the security of the following usage of SHA512:

If I have two strings, **x** and **y**.
Is it possible to derive SHA( **x** ) and SHA( **y** ) from SHA( **x+y** ) or reversed? 
**x+y** is string **x** concatenated with **y**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe http://security.stackexchange.com/ would be a better forum for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHA512 is pre-image, second-primage and prefix-preimage resistant.

Consequently:

- Finding any X given a SHA512(X) is hard.
- Finding any X given a SHA512(X+Y) and Y is hard
- Finding any X given a SHA512(Y+X) and Y is hard.

Given SHA512(X) and SHA512(Y) it is also hard to compute SHA512(X+Y) because SHA512 is not a linear function.

Generally speaking SHA512 is resistant to all known attacks other than a brute-force of X is X comes from a small set -- so for example if the SHA512(X) is the SHA512 of a password and the password is weak, it may be possible to find X by brute force, but this is due to the fact that your choice of X is broken, not that SHA512 is broken.

In general, if X is difficult to guess, SHA512(X) does not reveal any features of X.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "no". That would make a hash function (like SHA512) useless for keyed hashing schemes like [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Comment: Slightly more extensive: hash algorithms are supposed to be invulnerable against *length extension attacks* which is what you seem to be looking for as a feature...